# Я создал текстовый редактор и хочу сделать так, чтобы в не можно было запускать скрипты других языков.Как так сделать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

bind сделаю, надо только,то что мне нужно для запуска скриптов!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import fileinput
import subprocess
from re import split
import math

sa = None
text34 = None


def _open():
    global sa
    sa = askopenfilename()
    print(sa)
    f = open(sa, "r", encoding='utf-8')
    content = f.read()
    txt.delete(1.0, END)
    txt.insert(END, content)


def _save():
    global sa
    global content
    content = txt.get(1.0, END)
    f = open(sa, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()


def save2():
    global sa
    if sa is None:
        sa = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("text file", "*.txt"), ("python file", "*.py"),
        ("javascript file", "*.js", ), ("php file", "*.php"), ("c++ file", "*.cpp"), ("html file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    _save()

def _about():
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')
    win.geometry('300x200')
    lab = Label(win, text="First string version 1.5\n"
                          "Developer:NewModernSoft\n"
                          "2019.02.16\n"
                          "Copyrighted by NewModernSoft©")
    lab.pack()


def _exit():
    global sa
    if askyesno("Exit", "Saved changes?"):
        if sa is None:
            sa = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("text file", "*.txt"), ("python file", "*.py"),
            ("javascript file", "*.js", ), ("php file", "*.php"), ("c++ file", "*.cpp"), ("html file", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
        _save()
    root.destroy()


def _newwindow():
    subprocess.call('First_String.exe')


def update_word_count(event):
    text = txt.get(1.0, END)
    word_count = len(text.split())
    label_count.config(text='Words count: {}'.format(word_count))

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

root.geometry("1000x800")

root.iconbitmap('First_String.ico')

root.title("First String")



txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

frame = Frame(root, height=30)
label_count = Label(frame, text='Words count: 0')
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
label_count.pack()

txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
txt.bind('<KeyRelease>', update_word_count)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')

m = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=m)

fm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label="New", command=_newwindow)
fm.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
fm.add_command(label="Save", command=save2)

hm = Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label="About Program", command=_about)
hm.add_command(label="Exit", command=_exit)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Зря создали. emacs уже давно создали)

Comment: [Читайте тут](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)